# I cannot reinstall node.js on windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows

I need help reinstalling node.js but I keep this error when I uninstall the previous node

```
The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed.
This can occur if you are running Windows in Safe mode or if the Windows Installer is not correctly installed
```

I then try reinstalling msiexec.exe to see if I can fix the error in the windows installer but this popped up

```
ren msi.dll msi.old

ren msiexec.exe msiexec.old
bash: cd: %windir%system32: No such file or directory
```

The window installer service is running I check and I try using other packages like chocolatey but I still get the error (Generic MSI error).
As a last resort, I deleted the node folder from the program file but that didn't work. please I need help saving this

Comment: Try restarting your computer

Comment: I did so but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: I try using Microsoft program install and uninstall troubleshooter, it help to delete node but I still get this error when I try to install ```The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed.
This can occur if you are running Windows in Safe mode or if the Windows Installer is not correctly installed. Contact your support personnel for assistance```

Answer (score 2):

I got the error too

This is how i solved it

***1-)*** I ran your command line as administrator then

***2-)*** I typed sfc /scannow in cmd and entered

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32895921)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by downloading the latest nodejs zip file and then edit the environment variable by adding `C:\Programs Files\nodejs`.Note: add the content of the zip file to `C:\Programs Files\nodejs`  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try running the installer as an admin.

Answer (score 0):

Run command prompt as administrator and type in this code sfc /scannow the wait for it to finish repairs and try again